# Can't decrypt after encrypting with blowfish Java

Tags: java, encryption

Hello i'm new to Java and i have the following problem: i'm trying to encrypt the password of a user using the blowfish algorithm, but when i try to decrypt it back to check the authentication it fails to decrypt it for some reason.

```
public static String encryptBlowFish(String to_encrypt, String salt){
    String dbpassword = null;
    try{
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( salt.getBytes(), "Blowfish" );

        // Instantiate the cipher.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        //byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( URLEncoder.encode(data).getBytes() );
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( to_encrypt.getBytes() );
        dbpassword = new String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while encrypting");
        e.printStackTrace();
         dbpassword = null;
    } finally {
        return  dbpassword;
    }
}

public static String decryptBlowFish(String to_decrypt, String salt){
    String dbpassword = null;
    try{
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( salt.getBytes(), "Blowfish" );

        // Instantiate the cipher.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        //byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( URLEncoder.encode(data).getBytes() );
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( to_decrypt.getBytes() );
        dbpassword = new String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while decrypting");
        e.printStackTrace();
        dbpassword = null;
    } finally {
        return  dbpassword;
    }
}
```

When i call the decrypt function it gives me the following error:
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Well, this is not how to store passwords in your database, everyone who knows the salt could decrypt your password! Please read this for more information: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing multiple things wrong here:

- you are converting an encrypted value to a string.  not all bytes are valid strings.  store bytes directly in a database as a binary blob, not as a string (or convert it to hex or base64 first).
- you are confusing salt and key.  the thing you are calling `salt` in your code is actually a private key.  you don't appear to have a real salt, at all.
- you are encrypting a password.  that means you need to store a key somewhere (you cannot store it in the database or anyone that steals the database will be able to decrypt the passwords).  instead, you should use a hash.
- even then, you should not store passwords in this way.  not even if you use a salt correctly.  these days it is too easy to crack simply hashed passwords, even when salted.  instead, use the bcrypt library or PBKDF2.

[here are instructions for doing this correctly](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).  note that if you follow those instructions it *is* ok to store the password as a string (it has been converted correctly for you).